# SwiftUI Combine Debounce TextField

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, combine

I have a SwiftUI app with SwiftUI App life cycle. I'm trying to setup a standard way to add
typing debounce to TextFields. Ideally, I'd like to create my own TextField modifier that
can easily be applied to views that have many textfields to edit. I've tried a bunch of
ways to do this but I must be missing something fundamental. Here's one example. This
does not work:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text("You entered: \(searchText)")
                .padding()
            TextField("Enter Something", text: $searchText)
                .frame(height: 30)
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .onChange(of: searchText, perform: { _ in
                    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
                
                    let pub = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
                    pub
                        .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                        .collect()
                        .sink(receiveValue: { t in
                            self.searchText = t.first ?? "nothing"
                        } )
                        .store(in: &subscriptions)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.4

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think you'll have to keep two variables: one for the text in the field as the user is typing and one for the debounced text. Otherwise, the user wouldn't see the typing coming in in real-time, which I'm assuming isn't the behavior you want. I'm guessing this is probably for the more standard use case of, say, performing a data fetch once the user has paused their typing.

I like ObservableObjects and Combine to manage this sort of thing:

```
class TextFieldObserver : ObservableObject {
    @Published var debouncedText = ""
    @Published var searchText = ""
    
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        $searchText
            .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] t in
                self?.debouncedText = t
            } )
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var textObserver = TextFieldObserver()
    
    @State var customText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text("You entered: \(textObserver.debouncedText)")
                .padding()
            TextField("Enter Something", text: $textObserver.searchText)
                .frame(height: 30)
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            Divider()
            Text(customText)
            TextFieldWithDebounce(debouncedText: $customText)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TextFieldWithDebounce : View {
    @Binding var debouncedText : String
    @StateObject private var textObserver = TextFieldObserver()
    
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter Something", text: $textObserver.searchText)
                .frame(height: 30)
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }.onReceive(textObserver.$debouncedText) { (val) in
            debouncedText = val
        }
    }
}
```

I included two examples -- the top, where the container view (`ContentView`) owns the ObservableObject and the bottom, where it's made into a more-reusable component.

Comment: very elegant design 

Comment: @jnpdx Curious if the view would be recomputed everytime searchText changes, causing unnecessary renderings? Wouldn't `TextFieldObserver` be updated by the textfield user input and since it is a published property wouldn't the view be re-rendered?

Comment: I was thinking more on the lines of using one `CurrentValueSubject` for the textField's text so that the view doesn't get updated and then using another `@Published` property.

Comment: Strong reference in the sink subscription in TextFieldObserver causes memory leak,
change it to
 `.sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in self?.debouncedText = $0  } )`

Comment: This is works perfectly when the search is empty but I have 1 scenario please read the below scenario.

I have 1 form and I added debounce over there but I want to make it work when that form is in edit mode. currently, I just prefill the data in the form and it will hit the API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @yagniksuthar There's no way to adequately respond to that in a comment and without seeing the code associated with it. I suggest you start a new question with the relevant code/information.

Comment: okay thanks @jnpdx

Answer (score 19):

A little simplified version of text debouncer from @jnpdx

Note that `.assign(to: &$debouncedText)` doesn't create a reference cycle and manages subscription for you automatically

```
class TextFieldObserver : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var debouncedText = ""
    @Published var searchText = ""
        
    init(delay: DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride) {
        $searchText
            .debounce(for: delay, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$debouncedText)
    }
}
```

Comment: the published on searchText results in the view getting reloaded repeatedly unfortunately

Comment: @aehlke did you set it up correctly?

`searchText` is propagated to TextField, 
and `debouncedText` is used to, for example, to send network request

Comment: I don't recall. Now I'm using https://github.com/Tunous/DebouncedOnChange with success

Comment: Does this cancel the previous search if it takes too long, that is, does it only process the current search, discarding the previous one?

Comment: @Codelaby
It should cancel previous search by definition of debounce

Answer (score 11):

If you are not able to use an `ObservableObject` (ie, if your view is driven by a state machine, or you are passing the input results to a delegate, or are simply publishing the input), there is a way to accomplish the debounce using only view code. This is done by forwarding text changes to a local `Publisher`, then debouncing the output of that `Publisher`.

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    let searchTextPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
            .onChange(of: searchText) { searchText in
                searchTextPublisher.send(searchText)
            }
            .onReceive(
                searchTextPublisher
                    .debounce(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            ) { debouncedSearchText in
                print(debouncedSearchText)
            }
    }
}
```

Or if broadcasting the changes:

```swift
struct DebouncedSearchField: View {
    @Binding var debouncedSearchText: String
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    private let searchTextPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
        
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
            .onChange(of: searchText) { searchText in
                searchTextPublisher.send(searchText)
            }
            .onReceive(
                searchTextPublisher
                    .debounce(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            ) { debouncedSearchText in
                self.debouncedSearchText = debouncedSearchText
            }
    }
}
```

However, if you have the choice, it may be more "correct" to go with the `ObservableObject` approach.

Comment: I found this highly unreliable when typing somewhat quickly, it misses latest state updates

Answer (score 3):

Tunous on GitHub added a debounce extension to onChange recently.  https://github.com/Tunous/DebouncedOnChange that is super simple to use. Instead of adding .onChange(of: value) {newValue in doThis(with: newValue) } you can add .onChange(of: value, debounceTime: 0.8 /*sec*/ ) {newValue in doThis(with: newValue) }

He sets up a Task that sleeps for the debounceTime but it is cancelled and reset on every change to value.  The view modifier he created uses a State var debounceTask.  It occurred to me that this task could be a Binding instead and shared amount multiple onChange view modifiers allowing many textfields to be modified on the same debounce.  This way if you programmatically change a bunch of text fields using the same debounceTask only one call to the action is made, which is often what one wants to do.  Here is the code with a simple example.

```
//
//  Debounce.swift
//
//  Created by Joseph Levy on 7/11/22.
//  Based on https://github.com/Tunous/DebouncedOnChange

import SwiftUI
import Combine

extension View {

    /// Adds a modifier for this view that fires an action only when a time interval in seconds represented by
    /// `debounceTime` elapses between value changes.
    ///
    /// Each time the value changes before `debounceTime` passes, the previous action will be cancelled and the next
    /// action /// will be scheduled to run after that time passes again. This mean that the action will only execute
    /// after changes to the value /// stay unmodified for the specified `debounceTime` in seconds.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - value: The value to check against when determining whether to run the closure.
    ///   - debounceTime: The time in seconds to wait after each value change before running `action` closure.
    ///   - action: A closure to run when the value changes.
    /// - Returns: A view that fires an action after debounced time when the specified value changes.
    public func onChange<Value>(
        of value: Value,
        debounceTime: TimeInterval,
        perform action: @escaping (_ newValue: Value) -> Void
    ) -> some View where Value: Equatable {
        self.modifier(DebouncedChangeViewModifier(trigger: value, debounceTime: debounceTime, action: action))
    }
    
    /// Same as above but adds before action
    ///   - debounceTask: The common task for multiple Values, but can be set to a different action for each change
    ///   - action: A closure to run when the value changes.
    /// - Returns: A view that fires an action after debounced time when the specified value changes.
    public func onChange<Value>(
        of value: Value,
        debounceTime: TimeInterval,
        task: Binding< Task<Void,Never>? >,
        perform action: @escaping (_ newValue: Value) -> Void
    ) -> some View where Value: Equatable {
        self.modifier(DebouncedTaskBindingChangeViewModifier(trigger: value, debounceTime: debounceTime, debouncedTask: task, action: action))
    }
}

private struct DebouncedChangeViewModifier<Value>: ViewModifier where Value: Equatable {
    let trigger: Value
    let debounceTime: TimeInterval
    let action: (Value) -> Void

    @State private var debouncedTask: Task<Void,Never>?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onChange(of: trigger) { value in
            debouncedTask?.cancel()
            debouncedTask = Task.delayed(seconds: debounceTime) { @MainActor in
                action(value)
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct DebouncedTaskBindingChangeViewModifier<Value>: ViewModifier where Value: Equatable {
    let trigger: Value
    let debounceTime: TimeInterval
    @Binding var debouncedTask: Task<Void,Never>?
    let action: (Value) -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onChange(of: trigger) { value in
            debouncedTask?.cancel()
            debouncedTask = Task.delayed(seconds: debounceTime) { @MainActor in
                action(value)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Task {
    /// Asynchronously runs the given `operation` in its own task after the specified number of `seconds`.
    ///
    /// The operation will be executed after specified number of `seconds` passes. You can cancel the task earlier
    /// for the operation to be skipped.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - time: Delay time in seconds.
    ///   - operation: The operation to execute.
    /// - Returns: Handle to the task which can be cancelled.
    @discardableResult
    public static func delayed(
        seconds: TimeInterval,
        operation: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Void
    ) -> Self where Success == Void, Failure == Never {
        Self {
            do {
                try await Task<Never, Never>.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(seconds * 1e9))
                await operation()
            } catch {}
        }
    }
}

// MultiTextFields is an example
// when field1, 2 or 3 change the number times is incremented by one, one second later
// when field changes the three other fields are changed too but the increment task only
// runs once because they share the same debounceTask 
struct MultiTextFields: View {
    @State var debounceTask: Task<Void,Never>?
    @State var field: String = ""
    @State var field1: String = ""
    @State var field2: String = ""
    @State var field3: String = ""
    @State var times: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Field", text: $field).padding()
                    .onChange(of: field, debounceTime: 1) { newField in
                        field1 = newField
                        field2 = newField
                        field3 = newField
                    }
                Text(field+" \(times)").padding()
            }
            Divider()
            HStack {
                TextField("Field1", text: $field1).padding()
                    .onChange(of: field1, debounceTime: 1, task: $debounceTask) {_ in
                        times+=1 }
                Text(field1+" \(times)").padding()
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Field2", text: $field2).padding()
                    .onChange(of: field2, debounceTime: 1, task: $debounceTask) {_ in
                        times+=1 }
                Text(field2+" \(times)").padding()
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Field3", text: $field3).padding()
                    .onChange(of: field3, debounceTime: 1, task: $debounceTask) {_ in
                        times+=1 }
                Text(field3+" \(times)").padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MultiTextFields()
    }
}
```

I haven't tried the shared debounceTask binding using an ObservedObject or StateObject, just a State var as yet. If anyone tries that please post the result.