# Call async function from didSet

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to run some async/await code when a text box's content changes to get some results from the backend server and update the UI.

The text box uses this `searchTerm` published property in Swift but calling this async method in `didSet` locks up the UI.

```
//This is used to populate a list
@Published var results : ResultsData = ResultsData()

//This is used as a binding for a TextField
@Published var searchTerm: String = "a search term"{
    didSet {
        Task {                       
            self.results = await searchService.GetData(searchTerm: searchTerm)             
        }               
    }             
}
```

I have tried using `await MainActor.run{`, a `static` version of `results` and even global variables just to get the UI to update but it hasn't worked and the UI continues to freeze up as soon as I type something in the textfield.

How can I call this async method to get the results from the backend each time the user enters a character in the textfield?

Comment: Did you mean to write a `didSet` on `searchTerm`? Right now the `didSet` appears to be for `results`.

Comment: ah yes, sorry I'll update the question now

Comment: You can use Combine to subscribe to the property and call the api that way, I assume there’s articles or questions here on SO that could help you with that or you could solve this in the view by using `.task`. In either case you don’t want to send a new request for every keystroke so you need to handle that.

Comment: Use “task(id:)” don’t use those floating Task, you also likely want to debounce.

Comment: once you migrate to async/await and `.task` you can just remove the `@Published` and `ObservableObject` and go back to using just `@State` like you do for normal non-async.

Answer (score 1):

There are two topics here:

1. It looks like 'var results' is a function of your 'searchTerm' state.

Mark properties that define your state as @Published, and define the resulting properties as functions or calculated properties.

If you find yourself setting one @Published property as a result of setting another, you should ~probably~ rethink the current model.

Look into WWDC talks about SwiftUI State management to learn about this topic.

2. Async presentation handling

You currently "fire and forget" your Tasks, which means you cannot track progress, guarantee an order of completion, debounce, cancel, etc. An ideal solution would probably use Combine or Task handling (see [Async search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466453/async-search-bar)) to handle all of these details properly.

#1 & #2 can both probably cause the sort of UI Freeze you are experiencing.

Here is a sample solution (without extra functionality e.g debouncing).

```
import SwiftUI

class ResultViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var searchTerm: String = "a search term"
    
    func getSearchResult() async -> String {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(500))
        return "result for \(searchTerm)"
    }
}

struct ResultView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ResultViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("search", text: $viewModel.searchTerm)
            AsyncViewExample(loadData: viewModel.getSearchResult) {
                Text($0)
            }
            .id(viewModel.searchTerm)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct AsyncViewExample<AsyncData, Content: View>: View {
    let loadData: () async -> AsyncData
    let wrappedAsyncView:  (AsyncData) -> Content
    
    @State private var loadedData: AsyncData?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let loadedData {
            wrappedAsyncView(loadedData)
        } else {
            ProgressView()
                .task {
                    loadedData = await loadData()
                }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    ResultView()
}
```

Comment: You say to use Combine. That seems wrong, but show me: Where does your code do that?

Comment: Thanks, I edited that line to reflect that Combine is not really necessary. 

My sample solution implements the functionality of async search result; it is "without extra functionality e.g debouncing", which is what I meant you would need Combine (or some other additional functionality) for.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to craft a solution using parts from this answer. I've posted it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use task with id like below

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var searchTerm: String = "Xyz"
    @Published var result: <YOUR TYPE>
    
    func getSearchResult() async -> String {
        // Make api call
        self.result = <YOUR RESULT>
    }
}

struct ResultView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Type something")
            TextField("search", text: $viewModel.searchTerm)
        }
        // Observe searchTerm
        .task(id: viewModel.searchTerm) {
            // On change of search term wait 300 milliseconds
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(300))
            // Then check task cancelation & make api call
            if !Task.isCancelled {
                await viewModel.getSearchResult()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Noe you can just remove the old Combine object and do `result = await getSearchResult()` because `.task` already behaves like an object.

Answer (score 0):

Roy Rodney's answer put me on my way to a solution including a debounce, all within the same SwiftUI file without needing a ViewModel or published properties (not that there is anything wrong with using these)

Here is how I implemented my solution to call my async method each time a user enters a key in the textfield.

```
TextField(
                    "Enter term here",
                    text: $searchTerm
                ).onChange(of: searchTerm) { searchTerm in
                        searchTextPublisher.send(searchTerm)
                    }
                    .onReceive(
                        searchTextPublisher
                            .debounce(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                    ) { debouncedSearchText in
                        Task{
                            await myAsyncFunction(newValue: debouncedSearchText)
                        }
                    }
```

and here is my searchTextPublisher declared in the same SwiftUI file

```
  let searchTextPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
```