# How to run code only after a variable hasn't changed after a couple seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield, onchange

I have a TextField that runs a search when the bound variable changes. But I would like for it to wait a second or two before running the search in order to save on resources.

Here's an example:

```
TextField("Search", text: $searchBody)
    .onChange(of: searchBody) { query in
        print("Search Changed!")
        // Code here runs if searchBody doesn't change after 2 seconds.
    }
```

Comment: `debounce` from `Combine`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164898/swiftui-combine-debounce-textfield) may help

Comment: https://onmyway133.com/posts/how-to-debounce-textfield-search-in-swiftui/

Comment: Medium [link](https://medium.com/@carmineporricelli96/throttling-and-debouncing-in-swiftui-4f3cea9ffec5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should help :)

```
   TextField("Search", text: $searchBody)
       .onChange(of: searchBody) { query in
           print("Search Changed!")
           // Code here runs if searchBody doesn't change after 2 seconds.
           var tmp = searchBody
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
               if tmp == searchBody {
                   //Your code here
                   ...
           }
        
       }

   }
```